# Find the duplicate elements in arraylist and display

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

Can anybody help me? I need to write a program, where I have 10 elements in the `arraylist` and I need to find the how many duplicate values it has and count and display the values as wel.

Ex: say I have

```
list = {"stack", "overflow", "stack", 
        "yahoo", "google", "msn", 
        "MSN", "stack", "overflow", "user" }
```

Result should be:

```
stack = 3
overflow = 2
google = 1
msn = 2
yahoo =1
user = 1
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried before posting on SO.

Answer (score 8):

Use a HashMap.  Here is a simple implementation

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.put("stack", "overflow", "stack", "yahoo", "google", "msn", "MSN", "stack", "overflow", "user");

Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String str : strings) {
    if (counts.containsKey(str)) {
        counts.put(str, counts.get(str) + 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(str, 1);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Simple and Thanks for your Help :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library's `MultiSet`. It supports adding multiples of elements, and counting how many occurrences of each element the multiset contains.

```
Multiset<String> wordsMultiset = HashMultiset.create();
wordsMultiset.addAll(words);
for(Multiset.Entry<String> entry : wordsMultiset.entrySet() ){
     System.out.println("Word : "+entry.getElement()+" count -> "+entry.getCount());
}
```

Comment: Yup - *much* simpler than all the suggestions of using a HashMap...

Answer (score 3):

use `hashmap`
like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> occurrencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String word : list) {
    occurrencies.put(word, occurrencies.containsKey(word)
    ? occurrencies.get(word) + 1 : 1);
}
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : occurrencies.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Word: "+entry.getKey()
                     + ", occurences: "+entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String element : list) {
    if (frequency.contains(element)) {
        frequency.put(element, frequency.get(element) + 1);
    }
    else {
        frequency.put(element, 1);
    }
}
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : frequency.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap`

```
Map<String, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<String, Integer>`, and then iterate over your `ArrayList`.

**Then for each element: -**

- If it is already present in the Map, increment the `Integer` value for that element by 1
- If it is not present, add that element with an `initial Integer` value of 1