# Find duplicates in array list using Map<String, Integer> with input order

Tags: java

Hi everyone I am trying to print all the duplicated elements, this works fine but the outputs are not in order (either from user input or from the text file).
I want to print all elements with order (duplicates are not printed). How do I do that?
The codes are from this [Find the duplicate elements in arraylist and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947926/find-the-duplicate-elements-in-arraylist-and-display)
Thanks @Cory Kendall for the codes.

**********updated question: the code now works perfect with LinkedHashMap. Now I want the outputs to be printed with number bullets (ie, 1. name1 = 2 ) incrementally. Thanks

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
// suppose datas are entered by user incrementally or from a text files.

Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String str : strings) {
    if (counts.containsKey(str)) {
        counts.put(str, counts.get(str) + 1);
    } else {
        counts.put(str, 1);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: You say 1. `print all the duplicated elements` and 2. `print all elements with order (duplicates are not printed)`. Which one do you really want?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I want to print all the elements in order. THanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to remember insertion order in your Map, you need to use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). In your case you have to replace

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

with

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Comment: done, however now i want to display that list with number bullets incrementally, how can I do that with the codes above. Thanks

Comment: @user1986597: initialize an `int` outside of your loop and increment it once per loop.

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` is not ordered or sorted, use `LinkedHashMap` if you care about `insertion order`, or use `TreeMap` if you care about `natural order`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class FindDup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str[] = { "yogi", "ram", "ram", "yogi", "yogi", "yogi", "raju", "raju", "ram", "yogi", };
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String s : str) {
            if (map.containsKey(s)) {
                map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(s, 1);
            }
        }
        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + "---" + e.getValue());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) will retain order.

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
```

About `LinkedHashMap`:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order).