# Find all duplicates in ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList with elements, but that array list have some duplicates. Here is an example:

```
ArrayList<CoolObject> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
//arraylist.add(new CoolObject("In constructor, you need to put name for object"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("1"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("2"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("2"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("3"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("4"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("4"));
```

Also 'CoolObject' has method getName(). I need to get output like:

> ["2", "2", "4", "4"]

How I can do this?

Comment: Your expected output seems to contain duplicates, care to explain?

Comment: Which output is expected if the input is like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5]`?  It could be `[2, 2, 4, 4]`(sorted) or `[2, 4, 2, 4]` (keeping the order in initial list), or it does not matter?

Answer (score 0):

**I hope this solution will help you for your query.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Employee> data = Arrays.asList(
          new Employee(101,"emp1"),
          new Employee(102,"emp1"),
          new Employee(103,"emp1"),
          new Employee(104,"emp2"),
          new Employee(105,"emp2"),
          new Employee(106,"emp3"),
          new Employee(107,"emp3"),
          new Employee(108,"emp3"),
          new Employee(109,"emp3"),
          new Employee(110,"emp3"),
          new Employee(111,"emp3"),
          new Employee(112,"emp4"),
          new Employee(113,"emp4"),
          new Employee(114,"emp5"),
          new Employee(115,"emp6"));

          List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
          List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
          List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

        data.stream().map(Employee::getName).forEach(x -> {
            if(!list1.contains(x)) {
                list1.add(x);
            } else {
                list2.add(x);
            }
        });
        list1.forEach(x -> {
            if(!list2.contains(x)) {
                list3.add(x);
            }
        });
        list1.removeAll(list3);
        list2.addAll(list1);
        Collections.sort(list2);
        System.out.println("duplicate list:: " + list2);
    }
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

**Output**

```
duplicate list:: [emp1, emp1, emp1, emp2, emp2, emp3, emp3, emp3, emp3, emp3, emp3, emp4, emp4]
```

**Thanks**
*Girdhar*

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to find and keep the duplicates in the list providing that the object in the list has properly implemented methods `equals` and `hashCode`

1. Using `Collection::removeIf` + a predicate to detect a duplicate entry

a) For duplicate entries in the list `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` return *different* results:

```java
public static List<CoolObject> printDuplicates(List<CoolObject> list) {
    List<CoolObject> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
    copy.removeIf(x -> copy.indexOf(x) == copy.lastIndexOf(x));
    System.out.println(copy);
    return copy; 
}
```

b) Count frequency of the object using `Collections.frequency`

```java
public static List<CoolObject> printDuplicates2(List<CoolObject> list) {
    List<CoolObject> copy = new ArrayList<>(list);
    copy.removeIf(x -> Collections.frequency(list, x) < 2);
    System.out.println(copy);
    return copy; 
}
```

Despite these methods are the shortest they are the least efficient because of high time complexity O(N^2).

2. Convert the input list to the map of frequencies, filter out the unique entries (the order of entries may be changed)

```java
public static List<CoolObject> printDuplicatesStream(List<CoolObject> list) {
    List<CoolObject> dups = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x)) // Stream<CoolObject, List<CoolObject>>
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1) // keep the duplicates 
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // Stream<List<CoolObject>>
        .flatMap(List::stream)    // Stream<CoolObject>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(dups);
    return dups; 
}
```

3. Use a couple of `Set`to track unique and duplicate entries

```java
public static List<CoolObject> printDuplicatesSet(List<CoolObject> list) {
    Set<CoolObject> uniques = new HashSet<>();
    Set<CoolObject> duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    
    list.forEach(x -> { 
        if (duplicates.add(x)) { 
            uniques.add(x);
        } else {
            uniques.remove(x);
        }
    });
    duplicates.removeAll(uniques);
    
    List<CoolObject> dups = list.stream()
        .filter(duplicates::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(dups);
    return dups; 
}
```

Tests (with a slightly changed order):

```java
List<CoolObject> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
//arraylist.add(new CoolObject("In constructor, you need to put name for object"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("1"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("2"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("3"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("4"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("2"));
arraylist.add(new CoolObject("4"));

printDuplicates(arraylist);
printDuplicates2(arraylist);

printDuplicatesStream(arraylist);
printDuplicatesSet(arraylist);
```

Output

```
[2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 2, 4, 4]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

there are a lot of questions and answers like that on this site! Have you thought about using hashMap?
example question & answer:
[Find the duplicate elements in arraylist and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947926/find-the-duplicate-elements-in-arraylist-and-display/12947975)
I recommend trying to find the answer through Google first- it's a skill as important as programming itself in Comp Sci :) Good luck!

Comment: Yes, i try to find answer on Google, SO. But i need to get output like [2, 2, 4, 4]. But i found a little diffrent answers

Comment: You should vote to close this as a duplicate rather than posting an answer saying it’s a duplicate

Comment: I see, sorry Joakim. @katch I do think google has your answer. Google "print out the duplicates in an Array".  Or do an example that isn't exactly your exercise, but will help you understand the Arrays concept.